# Weird Behaviour of next() In Reactive Chain

Tags: java, reactor

To start with, here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("737", "747");
    Flux<String> f1 = Flux.fromIterable(l1);

    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("757", "777");
    Flux<String> f2 = Flux.fromIterable(l1);

   f1.mergeWith(f2)
    .doOnNext(a -> System.out.println(a))
    .next()
    .subscribe(a -> System.out.println(a));
}
```

Here's the output that I am expecting:

```
737

747

757

777

737
```

As the documentation of `next()` says, it takes the first element, creates a `Mono` out of it, and cancels the subscription.

The output that I am getting is:

```
737

737
```

Comment: it's impossible to get output 777 or 757, since your f2 is also based on l1, instead of on l2

Comment: @Stultuske True, but it's also impossible for other reasons. Simply changing it to `l2` in this case will make no difference.

Comment: at least those values would be in the data being used :)

Comment: next() will take the first element from the merged flux and cancel subscription so that's why you are getting print on 737 (onNext) and since it's the first element the print in subscribe print it another time. You can see that the complete signal is emitted after

Comment: You do `next` which takes the first element and creates a `Mono`, then subscribe to the `Mono`, which consumes all the elements (i.e. the only element).

Comment: there's probably a typo on Flux<String> f2; it should be created from l2?

Comment: @Daniele yes, there's a typo. It is created from l2.

Comment: How is this related to RxJava? Please don't automatically tag questions with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the `next()` takes the first element of a flux create a Mono. A Mono is 0 or 1 value. So when subscribing you will only receive the first value of the original Flux.

Take a look at the marble:
[image: next marble]

See how the complete is emitted right after the first value.

So if we apply this to your code we have

```
737 -> 747 -> 757 -> 777 |

onNext

print 737

next()

737 -> |

subscribe()

print 737
```